# Trigger insert on related table mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm having a problem when I insert into `tarifa_data`. This table is related with `translator_tarifes_data_facturacio` and this with `tarifes_translator`. On the `translator_tarifes_data_facturacio` table I want to save the both id relation `tarifa_data` and `tarifes_translator`.

Here is the design table:
[table design http://project2be.com/stack/tables.png](http://project2be.com/stack/tables.png)

On the `tarifa_data` I created this trigger to insert into `translator_tarifes_data_facturacio` for each row the id. This is the trigger:

```
USE `proje169_gl`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_INSERT_id_init` AFTER INSERT ON `tarifa_data` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO translator_tarifes_data_facturacio (tarifa_data_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
END
```

When I insert on `tarifa_data` for instance `INSERT INTO tarifa_data(id, data) VALUES ('1','2013-12-15 00:00:00')` I'm getting this error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`proje169_gl`.`translator_tarifes_data_facturacio`, CONSTRAINT `fk_translator_tarifes_data_facturacio_tarifes_translator1` FOREIGN KEY (`tarifes_translator_id`) REFERENCES `tarifes_tra)
```

Any idea?

EDIT: This is the entire table:

[table design http://project2be.com/stack/tables1.png](http://project2be.com/stack/tables1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserted into table `translator_tarifes_data_facturacio` you need the values ​​for both columns `tarifa_data_id` and `tarifes_translator_id`.

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_INSERT_id_init` AFTER INSERT ON `tarifa_data`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tarifes_translator` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);
    INSERT INTO `translator_tarifes_data_facturacio` (`tarifa_data_id`, `tarifes_translator_id`) VALUES (NEW.`id`, LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41f507/1)</kbd>

Comment: But, if I have another table related with `translator_tarifes_data_facturacio` on the same way as `tarifes_translator`, how can I do that?

Comment: @acasanovas: If you can show that other table, and how this related to the "translator_tarifes_data_facturacio" table will be helpful.

Comment: @acasanovas: Please, can you include the image in the original question?